# How can I make clap ignore flags after a certain subcommand?

Tags: rust, clap

Let's say I'm writing a command-line program called `foo`, using [clap](https://crates.io/crates/clap) as the arguments parser:

```rust
#[derive(Debug, Parser)]
struct Cli {
    #[command(subcommand)]
    pub command: Commands,
}

#[derive(Debug, Subcommand)]
enum Commands {
    Run {
        executable: OsString,
        args: Vec<OsString>,
    },
}
```

---

One of the things it's supposed to do is run other command-line programs. For example, to tell `foo` to run the executable `bar`, the user would run:

```bash
foo run bar
```

If the user tries to pass flags for `bar`:

```bash
foo run bar --baz
```

...I would like them to be captured as raw arguments so that they can be passed directly to `bar` like so:

```
Cli {
    command: Run {
        executable: "bar",
        args: [
            "--baz",
        ],
    },
}
```

However instead of capturing it as a raw argument, clap parses it as a flag for `foo` to handle.

Is there any way to tell clap to ignore any flags it sees after a certain point?

---

I'm aware that the user could tell clap to stop parsing subsequent arguments as flags like so:

```bash
foo run -- bar --baz
```

I'd like to avoid this workaround if possible, since it's more verbose than necessary and it's somewhat counterintuitive from a user perspective. Usually you put in a `--` to avoid having args processed as flags, not the other way around.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few thing will be helpful here:

- [`Arg::trailing_var_arg`](https://docs.rs/clap/4.1.8/clap/builder/struct.Arg.html#method.trailing_var_arg): Tells clap that this is a "VarArg" and everything that follows should be captured by it, as if the user had used a `--`.
- [`Arg::allow_hyphen_values`](https://docs.rs/clap/4.1.8/clap/builder/struct.Arg.html#method.allow_hyphen_values): Tells clap to allow values which start with a leading hyphen (`-`).
- [`Command::disable_help_flag`](https://docs.rs/clap/4.1.8/clap/struct.Command.html#method.disable_help_flag): Tells clap to not look for a `--help` flag after this command (or subcommand), and to instead treat it as a raw value.

These options aren't all supported by the clap derive interface, so you will have to implement the `Args` trait manually using the builder interface. Here's how you could do that for the example in the question:

```rust
#[derive(Debug, Parser)]
struct Cli {
    #[command(subcommand)]
    pub command: Commands,
}

#[derive(Debug, Subcommand)]
enum Commands {
    Run(RunArgs),
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct RunArgs {
    executable: OsString,
    args: Vec<OsString>,
}

impl FromArgMatches for RunArgs {
    fn from_arg_matches(matches: &ArgMatches) -> Result<Self, clap::Error> {
        let executable = matches
            .get_raw("executable")
            .and_then(|mut executable| executable.next())
            .map(|executable| executable.to_owned())
            .ok_or(clap::Error::new(ErrorKind::MissingRequiredArgument))?;

        let args = matches
            .get_raw("args")
            .unwrap_or_default()
            .map(|i| i.to_owned())
            .collect();

        Ok(Self { executable, args })
    }

    fn update_from_arg_matches(&mut self, matches: &ArgMatches) -> Result<(), clap::Error> {
        *self = Self::from_arg_matches(matches)?;

        Ok(())
    }
}

impl Args for RunArgs {
    fn augment_args(cmd: Command) -> Command {
        cmd.disable_help_flag(true)
            .arg(
                Arg::new("executable")
                    .required(true)
                    .allow_hyphen_values(true),
            )
            .arg(
                Arg::new("args")
                    .action(ArgAction::Append)
                    .allow_hyphen_values(true)
                    .trailing_var_arg(true),
            )
    }

    fn augment_args_for_update(cmd: Command) -> Command {
        Self::augment_args(cmd)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this helped! I've edited the answer to include some other options that were necessary to make it work, as well as some example code.